# Make Jenkins job B (Running on Jenkins Server X) dependent on Jenkins A (Running on Server Y)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two jobs running on two different Jenkins Server Machines.

Job A => Server Y (Development Server)

Job B => Server X (Testing Server)

Job B, runs every 15 minutes continuously 365 days. Now, when Job A runs then Job B fails, as Job A is the code deployment. So, ideally my Job B should hold and not run during the time of Job A run.

Can someone please help with either any plugin that can help achieve this or any script and how to configure it.

Just to put it in a simple way, both these jobs should not run concurrently

Answer (score 0):

There are two options in your case:

1. Switch your infrastructure from two Jenkins masters to one Jenkins master with two slaves running on server X and server Y. Then you can use [Build Blocker plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin).
2. Use Jenkins REST API to communicate between server X and server Y.

   For example, as first build step of job B you can check if job A is in running state:

   ```
   curl -X GET -i 'http://{y-host}:{y-port}/job/{job-A-name}/lastBuild/api/json'
   ```

   There is `building` property in the response, which can tell about current job status:

   ```
   {
       "building": false,
       "displayName": "#22",
       "duration": 127163,
       "estimatedDuration": 123022,
       // many more data...
   }
   ```

   If job A is running (`"building": true`), then you can pause or abort your job B.

   And vice versa, you can check if the tests are running on server X before you start deployment on server Y.

Comment: But does this work if i have the job on a different server am looking for? I see in the below screenshot from the image on the plugins site that we specify the job names, but i doubt if we can give job names on a different server?
 https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/62063114/build-blocker-plugin.png?version=1&modificationDate=1340569111000&api=v2

Comment: Oh, I see, you have **two Jenkins masters**. In such case the only option is to use REST API. I updated my answer with some suggestions about how you can use it.

Comment: I will try this one and update with the results Alex. Thank you very much in advance.